# How to get radio button's choicename and choicevalues both in shiny r

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I want to get the radio button's choicename and choicevalue in shiny R. I am storing these value in a database to record the user's response (i.e both the option that user selected and the value for that option).

```
 lapply(1:(numAssets), function(i) {

  list(
    tags$hr(h4(df$quiz_questions[i])),
    radioButtons(paste0("r", i),label = NULL, selected = "",  
                 choiceNames = options[[i]],
                 choiceValues = values[[i]], inline = T)  

  )
})
```

This is the code to create the radio buttons based on the options that are stored for each question.

Now i want to get their choicenames and choicevalues for each radio button.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing those two vectors in a data.frame?

```
data.frame(choiceNames = options,
           choiceValues = values)
```

Comment: The choiceNames and choiceValues are arguments of radioButtons so it wont be viable to store them this way. Also how will I fetch this values in server.R ?

Comment: Could you expand your question with a more complete MWE? Then I will be able to answer your comment. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Generally speaking, it should be easier to store this information from the data you are using to create the object, instead of trying to extract it from te radioButtons later.